# wp-admin ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT only on certain networks

Tags: wp-admin

Okay, I have this strange issue with my WordPress blog since two days. The website works perfectly fine on my office network (Wi-Fi), I'm able to login to the dashboard either via laptop or mobile and post the content.

But, when I come back home and try to login, the wp-admin page shows ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT error, or sometimes redirects to login.php page and shows 404 Not Found error.

I contacted my host and they say there's no problem with the servers.

The strange part is, when I try to login to the website on my mobile network, which is a different ISP, I'm facing the same problem since two days.

I cleared the cache, flushed the DNS, but still the same problem.

However, I'm able to login via a proxy server (kproxy, for example).

Answer (score 0):

You may receive a message such as "Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded" or "Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded". This means that it is taking to longer for a process to complete and it is timing out. There are a number of ways to fix this error.

Editing .htaccess

Make sure you back up .htaccess before you edit it.

Add the following line to .htaccess:

php_value max_execution_time 60
Editing php.ini

Add the following to php.ini

max_execution_time = 60

If you are unsure of how to make these changes, or if you are on shared hosting that prevents you from making them yourself, you should contact your hosting provider and ask them to increase your maximum execution time.

Comment: please also check this link : https://www.ionos.com/digitalguide/hosting/technical-matters/err-connection-timed-out/